# jquery datatables undefined is not a function

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am current using a Ajax function provided by the datatables i only change the url to my own url and the number of columns. This is the error i get

[image: Error]
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
  `$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('working');
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": false,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "ViewOwnConsultServ",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns" : 
            [
                {"data" : "lecturename"}, 
                {"data" : "date"},
                {"data" : "starttime"},
                {"data" : "endtime"}, 
                {"data" : "school"} , 
                {"data" : "team"} , 
                {"data" : "status"} , 
                {"data" : "problem"} 
            ]
    } );
} );`
Here is an my HTML

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Lecturer's Name</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Start Time</th>
                    <th>End Time</th>
                    <th>School</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Teacher's note</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

I suspected it was something to do with my json but i checked. The below shows an example of my servlet. Does the datatables column should be == to the number of parameter of my json string?

[image: Servlet json]

Lastly this is an example of my json output

```
"data":[{"id":0,"staffid":0,"lecturename":"","starttime":"1pm","endtime":"2pm","roomno":0,"school":"Northland Secondary School","team":"northland","status":"Unconfirmed","date":"01/19/2015","problem":" can i PLEASE CONSULT YOU ON MATTER THAT DONT EXIST"},
```

Oh i forgot this are my imports

[image: imports]

Comment: Looks like you are not loading dataTables plugin.

Comment: Oh i just forgot to add the scripts part in just added them, thanks for commenting :) but it is still not working though are the scripts correct?

Comment: you need to add the second script(jquery library jquery-1.11.1.min.js) before all other script files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: scripts]
 AVOID DUPLICATE SCRIPTS works for me because I re added into a black jsp page with certain js scripts. Because i din't realize there were other scripts at the bottom of the page